# ajax call does not fire jquery code

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

Hi
In my script I am trying to call a page through ajax and then insert the contents of that page in the dom. The target page has this code:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1; // globally available
$(document).ready(function() {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart-container-1',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
     },
     title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
     },
     xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
     },
     yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
     },
     series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
     }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
     }]
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<div id="chart-container-1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

It is from highcharts script. When I make the ajax call I just get an empty div. Nonetheless when I run the page without the ajax call it runs just fine.

EDIT:
The page I am requesting contain jquery script, however I not using jquery script to call it. I am using these functions instead:

```
function callAHAH(url, pageElement, callMessage, errorMessage) {
 document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = callMessage;
 try {
 req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* e.g. Firefox */
 } catch(e) {
   try {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  /* some versions IE */
   } catch (e) {
     try {
     req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  /* some versions IE */
     } catch (E) {
      req = false;
     } 
   } 
 }
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {responseAHAH(pageElement, callMessage, errorMessage);};
 req.open("GET",url,true);
 req.send(null);
}

function responseAHAH(pageElement, callMessage, errorMessage) {
var output = '';
if(req.readyState == 4) {
  if(req.status == 200) {
     output = req.responseText;
     document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = output;
     } else {
     document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = errorMessage+"\n"+output;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an ajax call? Could you post the ajax part as well?

Comment: I can't see any ajax in here. Url to the page will be helpful to detect what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will edit the post and submit the ajax function. It is a facebook application that I have not published yet, and I am using tabs so that is why I am using ajax

Answer (score 2):

jQuery AJAX calls strip script tags out of the response unless you have set the datatype option to "html"

Make sure you have set the datatype to html.

```
$.ajax({url:"/sompage.html",datatype:"html",type:"GET"});
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I am using custom made script for ajax calls and not jquery.

Comment: Maybe you should use jquery :-)

Comment: I would but 1- I never used jquery before so it seems a bit complex to me, 2- I need to make more than one ajax call and each one is based on the response of the previous one and I do not know how to do it in jquery

Comment: Thank you. With a bit of research and luck I got done with jquery

Answer (score 0):

if u use update panel

```
Sys.Application.add_load(your_function);
```